# PC got stuck while upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, 19.10

I had Ubuntu 19.04 on Dell Inspiron 15 PC. I was updating it to 19.10 via the GUI. In the middle of `Installing updates` my PC went blank and showed *Started BPFilter*. I switched it off and turned it on again. Then it displayed a black screen with "GNU GRUB version 2.04". Also the `Checking media` prompt displayed 2 times. It also showed up during previous a booting session and Ubuntu would load after that, but this time it wasn't loading.

```
Checking media [Fail]
Checking media [Fail]

                         GNU GRUB version 2.04

 Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.for the first word. TAB 
 lists possible completion. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or  
 file completion.

grub>_
```

Comment: Why did you switch it off?   Weren't even the sysrq keys working (ie. you couldn't switch to a text terminal to login? or the kernel wasn't responding to commands such as REISUB to cleanly shutdown your system?  Yes I know most people don't remember reisub etc, but phones allow searches online & wikipedia along with other sites will tell you the keys needed; search "sysrq"). I would boot a 'live' system and `fsck` (file system check) your disks because of the unclean shutdown.  If errors are detected & fixed - you may find it boots into your OS (even if you need to resume upgrade)

Comment: Dear sir/mam, I am literally a novice in such fields...whatever you just said above clearly went above my head. I have only recently started using Ubuntu and even before I was not such an advanced user with Windows.  So that's why in such situations my best attempt is to restart the computer. Only 3 months back  I had taken CS as my engineering subject, hence it is only these days I have started exploring around. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the above window only, I typed:

```
grub>insmod linux
grub>insmod normal
grub>normal
```

Pressing Enter after this opens a Window with few different options:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced Options for Ubuntu

and some other options...

Choose the first option, and then choose a kernel in Recovery Mode (only the latest version of the kernel worked for me, after using other 2 I had to redo the process).

This again will pop up another set of Menu options. Choose **Repair Broken Packages**. After the process is complete, choose **Resume** option. This atleast worked for me. My PC rebooted with the Ubuntu version I was updating to minus a few updates.Thanks and best of luck. :)

EDIT: This worked for me to atleast start the system properly. But I still had to always type in the 3 grub commands. Eventually I had to clean install the OS in my PC. I used the university wifi to backup my data to Google Drive and then clean installed it. Now it works perfectly. Just a precaution, NEVER USE YOUR PC FOR ANYTHING ELSE WHILE IT IS UPDATING. I learnt it the hard way.

Comment: Good fix especially for a novice user! Feel free to "accept" your own answer.